# If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then $|f|$ is continuous at $x_0$

Tags: real-analysis

How I did this proof was I said that since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta$ implies $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. Then can I just say that since $||f(x)| - |f(x_0)|| \leq |f(x) - f(x_0)|$ then $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$? Or should there be another step?

Comment: @Faust7 $|x|$ is continuous at $0$... but not differentiable

Comment: @Surb ah my bad thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are right,
$$
\big||f(x)| - |f(x_0)|\big| \leq |f(x) - f(x_0)|
$$
is all that is required.

Answer (score 1):

You've got the idea right. Writing it neatly: let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|x - x_0| < \delta \implies |fx-fx_0| < \epsilon$. The same $\delta$ will work for $|f|$ since given $x$ such that $|x-x_0|< \delta$, we have: $$||fx|-|fx_0|| \leq |fx - fx_0| < \epsilon$$

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. It may just be the case that you need to prove or justify the fact that $$||f(x)| - |f(x_0)|| \leq |f(x) - f(x_0)|$$ which is technically not trivial, but also not hard to justify.

Comment: how can we justify this?

Comment: This is just the reverse triangle inequality. It is relatively easy to find a formal proof of this fact somewhere.